# php.ini wont work outside public_html directory

Tags: php

Just very quick question about php.ini file. I created my own on my php.ini file and it works fine if I put it inside my 'public_html' directory. However the problem is it can obviously be viewed in browser through HTTP requests.

So, I am trying to move it outside my 'public_html' directory however it does not seem to work when outside my 'public_html'.

I know I could perhaps set in my .htaccess the following to avoid it being read:

```
<Files php.ini>
  Order allow,deny
  Deny from all
</Files>
```

However I do not want to do this as my php.ini can still get cached by Google if it's in the 'public_html' directory. Is there any suggestions to make it work outside my public_html?

I am running an Apache server. Thanks for any suggestions

Comment: What webserver are you using? Apache?

Comment: The deny directive will stop the webserver from serving that file. Google cannot get around this.

Comment: Why don't you put that in you httpd.conf and block all access to php.ini?

Comment: Dont have access to httpd.conf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can't get cached by google if you block like that in `.htaccess`

Comment: Google does not always listen to .htaccess just caches what it likes I have found

Comment: @daza: you are COMPLETLY wrong. google can't caceh what the webserver DOESN'T send

Comment: Ok so the '.htaccess' needs to be in the public_html directory too I am guessing?

Comment: -1,  sorry I hate doing that but I had to. I mean, am I the only one that thinks having php.ini in a web accessible folder is totally ridiculous?  This is a fix that does not address the _real_ problem: php.ini is in a webfolder!

Comment: @stef: You are freely allowed to -1. But did you get that with that .htaccess you dont leave the php.ini opened to the public?

Comment: @yes123 The point I was _trying_ to make was that .htaccess should not have to protect php.ini. Your solution is a hack to work-around  the real problem.  .htacces's purpose of being is definitely not to protect php.ini! Get my point?

Comment: htaccess point is to protect files acess too. I strongly disagree with you especially whe the WM does not have accss to the global php.ini

Comment: [Some people](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3376573/should-external-libraries-be-inside-or-outside-my-php-project-directory-structure) don't even put the application's library code in a public web folder, [see how Zend Framework recommends their setup](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/project-structure.project.html) and ___notice the library folder is not public___.  There _may_ be a reason for keeping things out of reach.  It's ok if you can't understand this.  You can have php.ini, .htpasswd and even /etc/passwd file in web folder and rely on .htaccess, I was just giving you advice.

Comment: I can understand it and you are making no sense for me. Especially if in that php.ini he will just overwrite some setting (let's say memory_limit, or max_post_size) with just a couple of settings there + htaccess protecting it there is not point to behave paranoic there. I anyway respect your opinion if we are going to make some security-critical web app

Comment: @stefgosselin Placing files outside public_html and using .htaccess are two ways of telling Apache not serve a certain file/dir. The difference is htaccess is annoying and scary because can be accidentally deleted or the regex get misspelled and all of the sudden your file is public. Other than that they are quite the same.

Comment: @Ameen - This is a perfect case of .. "Even if something can be done a certain does not mean it should be...".  This is a very old post,  but my opinion has not changed.  It's not an .htaccess problem, it's a 'php.ini in wrong place' problem.  Lol.

Good-day, my friend

Answer (score 3):

You can use the `PHPRC` environment variable...see the documentation:

http://www.php.net/manual/en/configuration.file.php

Answer (score 1):

Two suggestions:

1. Ensure that Apache can find your php.ini (PHPINIDIR /path/where/php.ini/is/located)
2. Ensure the file is readable by the webserver user.

Comment: How can I ensure Apache can find my php.ini is there a way to point to the location through setting or PHP script using ini_set() etc?

Comment: You can check the Apache log files to see if an error is displayed when Apache starts up. However, if you specify the PHPINIDIR in the httpd.conf file as specified above, Apache should look in the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

How is it that you php.ini came to be in a web server accessible folder? It is the first time I hear of such a situation.

I thought hard on how you managed to do this, and the only answer I came up with is that you created a vhost in php folder. If that is the case, create another vhost out of the php.ini path, and remove the offending vhost.  See [this post](http://apptools.com/phptools/virtualhost.php) for examples.

Comment: Sorry made mistake in question. I did not create my server I created a php.ini file in my public_html directory thats how it got there